# Bitbucket Pipeline & Firebase

Tags: firebase, bitbucket-pipelines

I‘m trying to deploy my angular app with Pipelines to my Firebase hosting.

It works on my machine but the upload to firebase fails with

> Your CLI authentication needs to be updated to take advantage of new
>   features. ⚠  Please run firebase login --reauth

I already signed out on my machine as I read on the Internet. How can I help Pipeline to authenticate? Or is it another problem?